# How to set the TMemo height to fill text content in Delphi firemonkey

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I am using XE7.

I have a TMemo created in runtime.

I need enlarge your height to show all text lines.

I have tried these functions that I found on stackoverflow, but they aren´t working.

`Memo.height:=get_memo_height(aMemo)`
and
`Memo.height:=ResizeMemo(aMemo)`

I get height less than real height.

Regards, Luiz

```
//doesnt work
function get_memo_height(amemo:tmemo):single;
    var i:integer;
        astring:string;
        layout:ttextlayout;

    begin
      Layout := TTextLayoutManager.DefaultTextLayout.Create;
      astring:='';
      for i:=0 to amemo.lines.count-1 do astring:=astring+amemo.lines[i]+chr(10);
      Layout.BeginUpdate;
      Layout.Text :=astring;
      Layout.WordWrap := amemo.wordwrap;
      Layout.HorizontalAlign := amemo.TextAlign;
      Layout.MaxSize := PointF(amemo.width-amemo.ContentBounds.width,maxint);
      Layout.VerticalAlign := tTextAlign.taLeading;
      Layout.Font := amemo.Font;
      Layout.TopLeft := pointf(0,0);
      Layout.EndUpdate;
      result:=layout.textrect.bottom;
      Layout.free;
    end;



    //doesnt work
    function ResizeMemo(AMemo: TMemo):single;
    const
      Offset = 4; //The diference between ContentBounds and ContentLayout
    begin
      result := AMemo.ContentBounds.Height + Offset;
    end;
```

Answer (score 4):

try this work arround:

put a TText component inside the TMemo, aligned to mostTop, set Autosize True, HistTest False, and Opacity to 0

then in a event perform this action:

```
procedure TfnuevoItem.Memo1KeyUp(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
  var KeyChar: Char; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  Text1.Height:=0;
  Text1.Text:=Memo1.Text;
  Text1.RecalcSize;
  Memo1.Height:=Text1.Height+10; // set 10 or more offset
end;
```

Comment: This answer is genius. I was having trouble working out how to resize a memo to fit the content reliably, and this is the only solution that works so far. By "reliably", resize to fit at any time during the process of the controls being created/shown.

Answer (score 1):

Some extra manipulation on Neri Bocchi's code.
The intention here was to mimic the behaviour of Telegram and WhatsApp
on entering the text of a message.
As opposed to Neri Bocchi, I use this code snippet on OnChangeTracking event because it updates the height of the TMemo when delete key is being pressed continuously.

```
TMainForm.Memo1OnChangeTracking(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Text1.Height := 40;
  Text1.Text := Memo1.Text;
  Text1.RecalcSize;
  if Text1.Height < 100 then
  begin
    if Text1.Height > 40 then
    begin
     Memo1.ShowScrollBars := false;
      lyMessage.Height := Text1.Height + 8; // set 10 or more offset
    end
    else
    begin
      Memo1.ShowScrollBars := false;
      lyMessage.Height := 48;
    end;
  end
  else
    Memo1.ShowScrollBars := true;
end;
```

Comment: Nice! For Mobile I would use TextScale. The 1st line (setting the height all time) I think is unnecessary.